# How to get date from parse.com and set it to MM/DD/YYYY in android

Tags: android, eclipse, date, parse-platform

I am trying to get the **createdAt** date from **Parse.com** and let it be in the format: **"DD/MM/YYYY"** and put it in a textview but it's not working.

This is the code I wrote:

```
dateCreatedText.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("DD/MM/YYYY").format(
                currentUser.getCreatedAt().getDay()+"/"
                +currentUser.getCreatedAt().getMonth()+"/"
                +currentUser.getCreatedAt().getYear()));
```

And this is the error I am getting:

```
01-10 18:41:55.018: E/AndroidRuntime(3314): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
01-10 18:41:55.018: E/AndroidRuntime(3314):     at java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:361)
01-10 18:41:55.018: E/AndroidRuntime(3314):     at java.text.Format.format(Format.java:93)
```

How can I let it work ?

Comment: the error says it all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do just:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
dateCreatedText.setText(formatter.format(currentUser.getCreatedAt()));
```

Comment: I tried it and I get this error: Unknown pattern character 'Y'